# Count of records that are created the same day

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am trying to create a array that should be something like this:

```
[ [created_at date * 1000, count record for that date],
  [created_at date * 1000, count record for that date], 
  [created_at date * 1000, count record for that date] ]
```

The created_at date is not exactly the same, because of minutes, hours and seconds. 
I was thinking is it possible to change created_at time on create to `00:00:00`

I have tried with this,

```
@kliks = Klik.all.map{|klik| [(klik.created_at.to_i * 1000), 1]}
```

But I have not figure out to sum those records that are created the same day. Also this loops create a array for every single record, I don't want duplicates of the sum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rails has [ActiveRecord::Calculations](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods.html#M000292) which is designed to do exactly this sort of thing at the database level. You should use it. In this case, `count` is the method you want:

```
@kliks = Klik.count( :group => "DATE( created_at )" )
```

This is equivalent to the following SQL:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) FROM kliks
GROUP BY DATE( created_at )
```

The `DATE()` function is MySQL changes a datetime (like `created_at`, e.g. `2012-02-27 10:08:59`) to a plain date (e.g. `2012-02-27`). No need to go converting things to integers or multiplying minutes and seconds, and no need to use `map` or any other method in Ruby.

Comment: I have the kliks in my database and the array is following the your code: [[1330285888000, 1], [1330296432000, 1], [1330354931000, 1]]. Two of the kliks are created the same day. Therefore there should only 2 arrays. Also the DATE function dose not seem to work correct.

Comment: @Jordan I think multiplication is necessary, as the OP is likely trying to represent the dates as the number of milliseconds since 1970, in order to create a Date object in JS for an existing plotting library (like flot). [However, this is separate from the original question of grouping and counting by date.]

Comment: I got it working it is just a hash instead of a array. {"2012-02-26"=>2, "2012-02-27"=>5}

Comment: the date should also be in milli seconds.

Comment: I did go with this solution: @kliks = Klik.count( :group => "DATE( created_at )" ).map{|k, v| [(Time.parse(k).to_i * 1000), v] }

Answer (score 3):

According to the [query guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group), you should try with

```
items = Klik.select("date(created_at) as creation_date, count(*) as count").group("date(creation_date)")
result = items.map { |k| [ k['creation_date'], k['count'] ] }
```

Comment: +1 for solution did use the count method with group which I found more clean.

Answer (score 1):

The following will produce the result you have asked for:

```
Klik.all.group_by do |k|
  k.created_at.beginning_of_day
end.map do |date, records|
  [date, records.length]
end
```

Comment: Note that this may be less efficient, transferring the full data from the SQL server to Ruby and then grouping and counting, instead of performing these actions on the RDBMS itself.

Comment: I agree!  I'd go with Jordan's answer.